# How to create the same HashMap that works in two different classes, without having to create another HashMap in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, multiple-inheritance

In the first class I created a HashMap:
HashMap<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
And then send a variable called name to a database. Code:

```
HashMap<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("name", name);
```

In the second class in Java, I want to send a variable called surname, in this class, but it must be in the **same HashMap, because I want to send it to the same database.**
Please how to do this in Android Studio? Because it is not possible to apply multiple inheritance, since the classes in Android Studio already extend the AppCompatActivity.

If you write only:

```
test.put("surname", surname");
```

Android won't understand the object called "test", because it does not extends the HashMap in the first class.

If you declare:

```
HashMap<String String> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("surname", surname);
```

it will send to another database, but I want it to send in the same database in the first class.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're referring to an actual "database" when you say database, but if it's a question of using a single map across several classes then you have a lot of options, too many options to really offer a good answer. Can you explain more about how and where you're using this map?

Comment: I am creating a system that contains multiple pages. So I take the data that the user has uploaded and send it to a database. So I created this HashMap to send the data together, which the user sent to the system. I've already created a database, and the submission works. The question is about the two-page HashMap. User data must be in the same HashMap, on different pages.
How to do this, please?

Comment: There is no database here. This code does not create a database, and instantiating a hashmap does not create a database. There's also no inheritance of any kind here. I think you're making a lot of assumptions that aren't necessarily correct. Maybe re-write your question with a small, complete, example of the code that works and the code that doesn't work, but shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: The database was already created. Please, it is not necessary to write the database code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a constants class

```
class Constants {
 public static final HashMap<String, String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
}

In other classes you can use the test HashMap

class Worker1 {
 public hashMapFunc() {
  Constants.test.put('this', 'this' );
 }
}

class Worker2 {
 public hashMapFunc() {
  Constants.test.put('that', 'that' );
 }
}
```

etc

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this, but the Android Studio did not recognized the object called "test", in the second class.

Comment: did you import the Constants class in the files you're calling the Constants.test ?